# Request timeout error while processing long running task

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm processing and printing 1000 records in my ASP.NET site. When I click submit button the page loads for a while and goes to Request timeout error. I tried to increase the request timeout but this doesn't look like a good solution. Please suggest a best solution.

Also, how do I update the UI while the request is being processed. I need to show how many records have been processed till now.

How about creating a new thread.? What are the flaws with multithreading in ASP.NET?

Comment: Does your solution lend itself to paging? It's unusual for a user to want to see 1000 records at a time.

Comment: I just need to show how many have been processed in numbers not in records.. For example, 12 of 1000 records have been processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could leverage SignalR to create a bi-directional communication channel between the server and the client which would process and feedback as necessary SignalR can be found here http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR on NuGet.

Comment: Awesome - I'd only ever seen SignalR used for 'chat' - but it's usage really makes more sense now. Thanks.

Comment: Can't we do something with AJAX?

Comment: Perhaps but possibly not as easily I wouldn't of thought, as far as I can tell SignalR was specifically created for this type of scenario because other technologies were more complicated or not as robust.

Comment: SignalR is definitely a great solution to this.  By having a bi-directional connection between client and server the server can shoot down a response to the client once a task has completed.

Comment: Thanks for the support N. Taylor Mullen - vote the question up to show extra support!